# Replacing y[x] with myPowerSeries

Tags: differential-equations

Consider:

```
myPowerSeries = Series[y[x], {x, 0, 3}]
```

Which produces this output.

```
SeriesData[x, 0, {
y[0], 
Derivative[1][y][0], Rational[1, 2] Derivative[2][y][0], 
  Rational[1, 6] Derivative[3][y][0]}, 0, 4, 1]
```

Then:

```
myODE = y''[x] + x y'[x] + y[x] == 0;
myODE /. y[x] -> myPowerSeries
```

Which produces this output.

```
SeriesData[
 x, 0, {y[0] + Derivative[2][y][0], 
   2 Derivative[1][y][0] + Derivative[3][y][0], 
   Rational[3, 2] Derivative[2][y][0] + Rational[1, 2] Derivative[4][
     y][0], Rational[1, 6] Derivative[3][y][0] + Rational[1, 6] (
     3 Derivative[3][y][0] + Derivative[5][y][0])}, 0, 4, 1] == 0
```

So it seems to replace each occurrent of y[x], y'[x], and y''[x] with myPowerSeries. Not sure why.

Then I try:

```
y[x] /. y[x] -> myPowerSeries
```

Which produces this output.

```
SeriesData[x, 0, {
y[0], 
Derivative[1][y][0], Rational[1, 2] Derivative[2][y][0], 
  Rational[1, 6] Derivative[3][y][0]}, 0, 4, 1]
```

Seems reasonable, but then I try:

```
y'[x] /. y[x] -> myPowerSeries
```

Which produces this output:

```
Derivative[1][y][x]
```

So, why does the myPowerSeries sometimes replace, sometimes not?

What am I not understanding here?

Answer (score 3):

The `FullForm` of is `Derivative[1][y][x]` so when Mma goes to match the pattern y[x], there is no match.

I'll use the code-simplifying assumption that you want `y[x] = x^2`.

The issue is that

```
y'[x] /. y[x]->x^2
```

evaluates to `Derivative[1][y][x]`.

Instead, try

```
y'[x] /. y->Function[x, x^2]
```

which evaluates to `2 x` as expected.

Comment: What you have written does make sense, but it it not really the question I am asking, which is why does the command myODE /. y[x] -> myPowerSeries replace y''[x], y'[x], and y[x] in the myODE = y''[x] + x y'[x] + y[x] == 0 with myPowerSeries.